# Таймер получения эмиссии

Tags: android, rxandroid, rxjava2

Есть источник данных.
Требуется выполнять действие если источник данных не эмиттил айтем за 3 секунды.

```
введите сюда кодLog.d("MAESTRO", "before: ");
                        ConnectableObservable.just(i)
                                .replay(1, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                                        Log.d("MAESTRO", "test: " + integer);
                                        return integer != REASON_GESTURE;
                                    }
                                })
                                .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(Integer result) throws Exception {
                                        viewModel.setAutoGeoPosition();
                                    }
                                });
                        Log.d("MAESTRO", "after: ");
```

Код выше не работает.

Comment: полагаю, что вопрос нужно доработать. Что не работает? А как должно работать? Что вообще делает этот код? Пока явный неуд.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо, чтобы после 3 секунд бездействия после события скролла по карте выполнялось событие, то код ниже работает норм:

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {

                @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
                @Override
                public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
                    if (i == REASON_GESTURE && !AUTO_GEO_POSITION_ON) {
                        viewModel.setAutoGeoPosition();
                        Observable.just(i)
                                .switchMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<? extends Integer>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public ObservableSource<? extends Integer> apply(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                                        return Observable.just(i)
                                                .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                .filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                                                        return integer != REASON_GESTURE;
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                })
                                .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(Integer result) throws Exception {
                                        viewModel.setAutoGeoPosition();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
```